# Configure company app on azure with consentscreen and ability for user to revoke access

Tags: azure

This is my scenario:
As an administrator on Azure I want to add an application for my colleagues. This application will access the Microsoft Graph API to access e.g. their calendar or OneDrive files. I'm using a PHP-application for my Proof-of-Concept.
The user must be able to do three things: review what this application needs as permissions, give consent, and later be able te revoke the consent.

I have tested this by using Microsoft's Graph Explorer website. It correctly asks for consent (when logging in as a different user!). And when this users logs in to portal.office.com can revoke the access to the Graph Explorer.

However, I cannot seem to get it working for an application I built myself. In Azure I go to "App registrations" and setup the keys etc. In the permissions I make sure that no option is selected that requires admin-consent. I have selected a few in the category 'Delegated permissions".

THe PHP app wil not run on Azure IaaS/PaaS but hosted somewhere else.

What suprised my is two things: 
- in my PHP-application I have to ask for a consent screen to appear. If I'm not asking for it, the app will skip it. Strange.
- in "My Account" it still says that the administrator granted access.

I've looked at the answer below, but that doesn't help either.
[How to revoke access to Microsoft APP for a user in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35717512/how-to-revoke-access-to-microsoft-app-for-a-user-in-php)

So, basically I'm looking for the same scenario as when I'm building an app to access e.g. Google Contacts. I've built that integration and works as expected and outlined above.

Any thoughts anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Oke, after conferring with Microsoft this is what I came up with.

The problem is that some permissions/scopes require admin consent. In that case a number of things happen:

1. a user is not forced to give personal consent
2. a user cannot revoke consent through the portal.office.com portal (My Account--> Applications)
3. if the permission requiring admin consent is removed, none of the two situations above change!

So, If you setup an application and you accidentally select a scope requiring admin consent, you're in trouble.

Furthermore, there is a global setting you should enable so end users will see a consent screen at all.....

```
PS C:\Users\xxxx> Connect-MsolService -credential $msolcred
PS C:\Users\xxxx> Get-MsolCompanyInformation | fl DisplayName,UsersPermissionToUserConsentToAppEnabled

DisplayName                              : <your domain>
UsersPermissionToUserConsentToAppEnabled : False
```

Have a look at this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2014/06/05/managing-user-consent-for-applications-using-office-365-apis/).

The new Azure portal gives a better list when choosing the permissions/scopes. In the second column there is an indicator for 'admin consent' that is missing in the v1-portal. So switch to the new portal and refrain from using those permissions requiring admin consent.